# How to attach access token to a google calendar API request

Tags: php, api, calendar, oauth-2.0

Several documents on authorizing Google APIs reference attaching an access token without giving an unambiguous example. The request I generate is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/mtnmath@mtnmath.com/events?ya29.1.AADtN
```

I have deleted most of the access token in the above line.
This token was obtained successfully with:

```
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");
```

and

```
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

in php. The token was taken from a structure with json_decode on `$client->getAccessToken();`

I am not sure the problem is attaching the token but it is one thing I am concerned about. The result was "403 Forbidden". I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I found a site that almost gives an unambiguous example although it still took two trys to get it correctly. The site is
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#callinganapi

The rule appears to be to append an access token add "?access_token=" followed by the token.